# What is the correct xlink namesapce to use in Docbook 5?

Tags: docbook-5

If I have the following Docbook 5 XML:

```
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <section>
        <title>LS command</title>
        <para xml:id="ls">
            This command is a synonym for <command linkend="dir">DIR</command> command.
        </para>
        <para xml:id="dir">
            This command is a synonym for <command linkend="ls">LS</command> command.
        </para>
        <para>
            <application xl:href="http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/">Emacs</application>
        </para>
    </section>
</article>
```

and I attempt to validate it against the Docbook 5 DTD downloaded from [here](http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.0/dtd/docbook.dtd) with:

```
xmllint --noout --dtdvalid docbook.dtd test.xml
```

I get the following error:

```
test.xml:1: element article: validity error : No declaration for attribute xmlns:xl of element article
test.xml:11: element application: validity error : No declaration for attribute href of element application
```

However, if I change the `xl` namespace to `xlink`, like so:

```
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <section>
        <title>LS command</title>
        <para xml:id="ls">
            This command is a synonym for <command linkend="dir">DIR</command> command.
        </para>
        <para xml:id="dir">
            This command is a synonym for <command linkend="ls">LS</command> command.
        </para>
        <para>
            <application xlink:href="http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/">Emacs</application>
        </para>
    </section>
</article>
```

Everything validates just fine. I got the `xl` namespace from the Docbook documentation [here](http://docbook.org/docs/howto/#introduction-ns) (and the example of using an article with an application that had a xref is straight from that documentation).

So why does `xl` fail when `xlink` succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually that the DocBook 5.0 DTD specifically listed the xlink:href attribute, and any others were not valid.